# jQuery combine two parts

Tags: jquery

How to combine these two parts into one

part 1

```
if ($('input.border-question').is(':checked')) {
    $('.as-hidden').show();
}else {
    $('.as-hidden').hide();
}
```

part 2 for click

```
$('input.border-question').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
       $('.as-hidden').show();
    }
    else if($(this).is(":not(:checked)")){
        $('.as-hidden').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "combine"? It appears as those two parts are combined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**:

```
$('.as-hidden').toggle($('input.border-question').is(':checked'));

$('input.border-question').click(function(){
   $('.as-hidden').toggle($(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.